# Issues getting multiple values from List of Maps

Tags: json, flutter, sorting, dart, hashmap

I'm trying to get the "alarm" array values from the following map.

```
{
  "time" : 12122,
  "alarm" : [
     {
      "title" : "BPM LOW",
      "title" : "BPM HIGH",
      "title" : "BPM MID",
      "title" : "BPM NULL",
    }
  ]
}
```

I have made a parser class with Quicktype and I'm managing to get to the alarm array but the problem is when I try to access the "tittle" value from the Map I only manage to get the last value of the Map.
Does anyone have a suggestion why it does not work?

Comment: A map contains key-value pairs where you map a given key to a given value. What you are doing, is overwriting the same "title" key to different values. I would suggest you to have "title" pointing at a `List` containing each of you values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample json data structure contains two objects:

- `time` which is number
- `alarm` which is an array of objects where each object contains 4 exactly the same keys - *title* and that's why you receive only one element of the array with title = "BMP NULL"

Your json most likely should be as follows:

```json
{
  "time" : 12122,
  "alarm" : [
     {
      "title" : "BPM LOW"
     },
     {
      "title" : "BPM HIGH"
     },
     {
      "title" : "BPM MID"
     },
     {
      "title" : "BPM NULL"
     }
    
  ]
}
```